# How to specify the number of epoch's my model should train for in Flux.jl

Tags: julia, flux.jl

I know I want to have my model train for 200 epoch's based on some analog tests I have done in other frameworks and previous models. How do I specific the number of epochs my model should train for in Flux.jl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flux provides a convenience macro called `@epochs` which can be used as follows:

```
julia> using Flux: @epochs

julia> Flux.@epochs 2 println("hello")
[ Info: Epoch 1
hello
[ Info: Epoch 2
hello
```

or in the case of our training loop:

```
julia> using Flux: @epochs

julia> @epochs 2 Flux.train!(...)
# Train for two epochs
```

You can find out more from the Flux.jl docs here: https://fluxml.ai/Flux.jl/stable/training/training/